# How do I switch a span tag's text to in input with the text as the input value?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to essentially switch from span to an input while keeping the text from the span and making that the value of the input...

```
$('#container').find('<span />').each(function() {
  $(this).replaceWith($("<input />").val(this.text));
});​
```

that's what I tried and couldn't get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the confusion between DOM and jQuery, try using:

```
$('#container').find('span').each(function() {
  $(this).replaceWith($("<input />").val($(this).text()));
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Vr4Vc/).

Your original code you were trying to use the DOM node `this` with something, I presumed, to be the jQuery `text()` method (albeit the parentheses were omitted).